# Maya file <maya console> No object name specified textScrollList

Tags: python, maya

[image]

```
cmds.frameLayout(label=all[0],borderStyle='out',collapse=1,collapsable=True,width=210)
cmds.columnLayout()
cmds.textScrollList(h=100,w=200,allowMultiSelection=True)
for i in range(0,size):
    cmds.textScrollList(edit=True,a=string[i])
```

It is my Python code

I want to ask why

```
cmds.textScrollList(h=100,w=200,allowMultiSelection=True)
for i in range(0,size):
    cmds.textScrollList(edit=True,a=string[i])"
```

There are error

```
"No object name specified textScrollList"
```

What can I do?

Comment: Hi and welcome on StackOverflow, your base question had a lot of formatting issues. Please follow the guidelines [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking a question. You really need to use the appropriate markdown when posting code, error codes, quotation and so on. Also please, refrain from using screenshots of your IDE. This is a waste of time for you (take screenshot, host it etc...) and for readers (not really readable, can't copy and paste into an IDE...)

Answer (score 0):

The error code speaks for itself, you need to specify a name for your `textScrollList` when you create and edit it. Or Maya won't be able to know on which `textScrollList` you want to append items.

This can be any alphanumeric character you want as long as there are no spaces in it (use underscore if needed).

```
cmds.textScrollList("I_like_painting_with_poop", h=100,w=200,allowMultiSelection=True)
for i in range(0,size):
    cmds.textScrollList("I_like_painting_with_poop", edit=True,a=string[i])
```

Consider trying to apply a naming convention for **all** of your UI elements.